# Mapping char** in JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

My native function accepts char ** as argument . Will anybody help me how should I pass it using JNI.

my native function protocol - long processInput(const char* str1 , char ** output);

Thanks

Comment: You need to write JNI starting from the Java perspective. Figure out what **Java** API would make sense for this functionality, then use JNI to connect things together. The JNI approach is that you write native glue code, it's not a mechanism for native functions *directly*. In this case, it seems like maybe you want to use a `StringBuffer` and append the output string to it. Or use an object for the return value to return a `long` and a `String`. Or, if the `long` is an error code, throw an exception. It's hard to tell without knowing what the function does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do this directly, but you can't easily call an arbitrary function name with JNI either - so you'll need a simple native wrapper method.  Start with the hello-jni sample from the Android ndk distribution samples/ directory, build it as is to make sure everything works, then change it to be something like this:

```
long processInput(const char* str1 , char ** output);

jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    //return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
    char *outputstr; 
    processInput("some input", &outputstr); 
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, outputstr); 
}
```

You will probably also want to add error checking, maybe get the input string from jni, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer (yet) but it is too long for a comment.

Start by writing a native function declaration in Java such that it fits into Java naturally. Maybe one of these would be appropriate:

```
static native String processInput(String input);
static native byte[] processInput(byte[] input);
```

Then, in order to wrap the function, you have to know:

- The meanings of the return value and each parameter.
- If the `char` parameters represent strings, what are the

  - character set,
  - encoding and
  - length/terminator protocol.
- What memory is the caller expected to allocate and/or free?
- The callee?
- If the return value is some special value, does that mean `output` is not relevant, in which case should the wrapper throw a Java exception or return a `null` string, `null` array or zero-length array?
- Java uses Unicode for strings. What should happen if characters can't be mapped to the character set used by the function?